# Try block returns String before body code is executed

Tags: java, gwt, try-catch, return

I'm coding a web application in GWT. I have a class that handles all my http requests and returns the response of the server. 
This is my current code: (the variable messageXml is defined as a constant)

```
try {

        Request request = builder.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if(200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    messageXml = response.getText();

                }
                else {
                    Window.alert("There was an error (1) :-(");
                    messageXml = "ERROR";

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Window.alert("There was an error (2) :-(");
                messageXml = "ERROR";

            }
        });
        Window.alert(messageXml);
        return messageXml;
    }
    catch (RequestException e) {
          Window.alert("Could not connect to the server :-("); 
          return "ERROR";
        }
```

When I call the method httprequest it returns the String first and after that it executes the code in the try body. 
For example when i do:

```
request object = new request();

    String test = object.httpRequest(file, type, requestData);
    Window.alert(test);
```

It outputs first null (because the String has no content yet) and after that the content of the String. Does anyone know why the method behaves likes this?

Comment: "the variable messageXml is defined as a constant" -- but you are assigning a value to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether `messageXml` is defined as a constant or not is not the issue here. `Request#sendRequest()` is an asynchronous operation so you cannot make any assumptions about when `messageXml` is assigned a value. See GWT's [Getting Used to Asynchronous Calls](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideGettingUsedToAsyncCalls) for more details. The correct way to use `Request#sendRequest()` is with a callback:

```
public void getMessageXml(String requestData,
                          final AsyncCallback<String> callback) {
  try {
    // Modify for your application.
    RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(Method.GET,
      "http://www.mycompany.com/getMessageXml");

    rb.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable caught) {
        callback.onFailure(caught);
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        if (Response.SC_OK == response.getStatusCode()) {
          callback.onSuccess(response.getText());
        } else {
          // Use a correctly typed exception here.
          callback.onFailure(...);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (RequestException rex) {
    callback.onFailure(rex);
  }
}
```

And to call the method:

```
object.getMessageXml(someRequestString, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    // Handle error.
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(String messageXml) {
    // Process response
  }
});
```